# Remove specific suffix from all files containing it

Tags: batch-rename

Long story short, OneDrive has taken all my files and renamed them to include the string "-DESKTOP-9EI0FN7" at the end of the file name, resulting in files such as:

`myTextFile-DESKTOP-9EI0FN7.txt`
`myVideo-DESKTOP-9EI0FN7.mp4`

So I'd like to write a batch script that finds all the files with that string in them, and renames them to remove the string, so:
`myTextFile-DESKTOP-9EI0FN7.txt` becomes `myTextFile.txt`

The problem is, I know nothing about writing batch files. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Test out with this bad boy:

```
find . -type f -exec rename -n -e 's/(.*)\-DESKTOP\-9EI0FN7(.*)/$1$2/' {} \;
```

If the output satisfies you, remove the `-n` portion and it does actually apply the changes.

Good luck, sir!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'm getting an error when I try run it though.
```FIND: Parameter format not correct```

Comment: You seem to be running the command in windows, is that correct? I was falsely assuming, you'd be running on a *nix distribution like Linux or MacOS. As far as that goes, this is no solution for you, as long as you wont run it through WLS, cygwin or similiar. I'm really sorry, for not asking beforehand (and not noticing, you're asking about "batch files").